# passing values to controller from directive

Tags: angularjs, function, controller, element, directive

I am creating a web app in which i created a directive for `input type file`

```
app.directive('customFileInput', [function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.on('change', function (evt) {
                    var files = evt.target.files;
                    scope.filename = files[0].name
                    console.log(scope.filename);
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

this is my directive for fetching the file name from

```
<input id="file" type="file" ng-model="mdfile" ng-change="filepath()" class="form-control"  custom-file-input />
```

this input field

now in my controller i want to pass the filename which i get from the directive

```
$scope.savefunction = function () {
            var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
                r = new FileReader();
            r.onloadend = function (e) {
                $scope.data = e.target.result;
            }
            r.readAsDataURL(f);

            $http.get('/employeeregistration.asmx/sav', {
                params: {
                    data: $scope.data,
                    //i want to pass the value here
                }
            }).then(function (response) {

            })
        }
```

how i can pass the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scope: false` in `DDO`

```
return { 
  restrict: “EA”, 
  scope: false, 
  link: function(scope, elem, attr){ 
   // write code here. 
  } 
}
```

name `filename` same in both place. [example](https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/L8s30pfp/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=L8s30pfp)

OR

Use `isolated scope`:

```
return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
        filename: "="
    },
```

see [isolated example](https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/fzyo5p0t/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=fzyo5p0t)
Hope this will help.

Comment: where i need to use isolated scope:?

In My controller?